# API Upgrade from .Net Framework to .Net 6.0 throwing 404 error in Postman

Tags: asp.net-core, http-status-code-404, asp.net-core-6.0, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have the following code which was working fine in .Net Framework but after upgrade it's throwing 404 error. This is basically my code :

```
[RoutePrefix("API")]
[BasicAuthenticationFilter]
public class APIController : ApiController
{
    [Route("Contact/New")]
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage NewContact(ContactAPIRequest request)
    {
        
    }

    [Route("Contact/Types")]
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetContactTypes()
    {
        
    }
}
```

I have it deployed on a website mangofruit.com(dummy name) and testing in Postman using https://mangofruit.com/API/Contact/New along with required authentication but I am getting a 404 error. I am also not able to access it using Visual Studio 2022.

Also https://mangofruit.com/API/Contact/Types throws an error 404.
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

In asp.net core 6 , Controllers in a web API are classes that derive from [ControllerBase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

The web API project template  like:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
```

You can try the below code:

```
   [ApiController]   
   [Route("[controller]")]   
    //[BasicAuthenticationFilter]
    public class APIController : ControllerBase
    {
        [Route("Contact/New")]
        [HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage NewContact()
        {
           ...
        }

        [Route("Contact/Types")]
        [HttpGet]
        public HttpResponseMessage GetContactTypes()
        {
          ...//do your staff
           HttpResponseMessage response = null;// for test
           return response;
        }
    }
```

result:
[image]

You can read [Create web APIs with ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-6.0) to know more.